# How to Generate PHP URL with login information

Tags: php, android, url, upload, generate

I want to generate a url thats points to a php file on the server
The url must be generated from login information entered namely
clientID(4 digits) ,Username and password, the url must then be calles into a server path string in the code
I am providing the space that the url must be called to

I have no idea how to go about this

Here is the code where the url must be generated

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements PermissionCallbacks {

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private static final int REQUEST_FILE_CODE = 200;

private static final int READ_REQUEST_CODE = 300;

**private static final String SERVER_PATH = "enter URL here";**

Button fileBrowseBtn;
```

Comment: Is there more code? Format it correctly so you can be helped.

Comment: I have formatted it correctly the rest of the code are the just activities and button onclicklistner etc. I dont have any ideo how to even start with generating an url from a login screen. the url must be called into private static final String SERVER_PATH = "enter URL here";